# Regarding Relatively setting UI in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout, dynamic

As in Android we can set in relativeLayout, textView below Button in xml file. Is there anything to set views relatively in IOS through storyboard or dynamically!! Please help as I am new to iOS, thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Autolayout will allow this. Review the free WWDC videos or look at a tutorial online or in iTunesU. Xcode 5.1 allows you to do everything in the Storyboard that you can do in code with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are constraints that you can add to elements in storyboards and there is autolayout.

I'd recommend looking at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html to see more about autolayout, it should let you set your layout dynamically